# How to make a HTML script that replaces the cookies of a website

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'd want to make a HTML script that will replaces the cookies of a specific website with a single button click.

PS: I have no idea how this is done, I've created extensions before, However I want to create a webpage that does the same job.

Answer (score 1):

HTML has no capability to do anything at all with cookies.

Cookies can be set with:

- Client-side JS for the origin the cookie belongs to
- HTTP response headers for the origin the response comes from

You cannot create a webpage which has control of the cookies belonging to an arbitary third party site. That would be a serious security problem.

Comment: Oh Okay, Thank you for the Answer, How ever it could still be done using an extension, So is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Extensions have to be explicitly installed by the user and granted permission to access other websites. There is **no** API that allows a website to manipulate the cookies of another website.

Comment: Okay, Which is fine by me, I just want an extension that could possibly do this, I have a little community that would like to change the UI of a specific website which I've been trying to implement using cookies.